# How to add animation on a button in android

Tags: android, android-animation

i am making an app in android platform. I wanted to add animation on the button of my app.The animation is like this : IF I PRESS A BUTTON ON A LAYOUT THEN ANOTHER BUTTON WILL ADD TO THE SAME LAYOUT WHICH WILL COME LEFT SIDE OF THE APP LAYOUT.THAT MEANS USER WILL SEE THE MOVEMENT OF  THE BUTTON  THAT IS COMING FROM LEFT SIDE OF THE APP.

I have no idea how can i do this. Please give me some useful blog/tutorial/documentation related to this. Thnaks in advance   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use viewswitcher to add a button onclick of another button as I have example to switch image and a linear layout with a button and textview.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/viewswitcher1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LinearLayout 2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewSwitcher>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prev"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.view.animation.Animation;
  import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button buttonPrev, buttonNext;
ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

Animation slide_in_left, slide_out_right;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    viewSwitcher1 = (ViewSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.viewswitcher1);


    slide_in_left = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
    slide_out_right = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    viewSwitcher1.setInAnimation(slide_in_left);
    viewSwitcher1.setOutAnimation(slide_out_right);


    buttonPrev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            viewSwitcher1.showPrevious();

        }
    });

    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            viewSwitcher1.showNext();

        }
    });
    ;
}
```

}

Comment: many many thanks for your reply. can you please give me the java code associated this xml file so that i can able to run this as i have no idea on ViewSwitcher. Please...please @snj